# hide some form information without changing from GET to POST

Tags: php

I have an array of ids and an array of corresponding values on a form.  The user chooses the value on the screen but I am using GET on my form to get the ids.  The problem is I need to convert the key back into the value on the second php page, except that the GET function did not send the value along with the id.  I do not want to send the value over the url and I do not wish to change the URL as it is now (or, by extension, change from GET to POST to hide the value).

Basically, what is the best way to make this conversion on the second php page having only sent the key over the url and not having the array as a variable on the second page?  I read something about super globals but I was not sure if that was the right way to go.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Posting some sample code might be helpful.

Comment: Some example code would be helpful as @Colin stated. Also, are you wanting to do `method="GET"` on the form, but keep a few of the form's inputs from displaying the URI? If so, @thescientist's suggestion of an AJAX request would suite you best.

Comment: Sorry, I am still working on the code right now and it is a mess.  I just wanted to know what my options were and SESSION was perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you don't want to send the value over the URL, then you could do an AJAX request to a PHP script and save the value in $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

If I got you, probably you are looking for $_REQUEST. 
It permits to read parameters from request in any case (post or get).

Comment: the issue is how the the values are sent to the server side URL (GET) vs. form (POST/GET) vs. AJAX (POST/GET), not necessarily how get their values once they are there.  Essentially, it is obfuscating the value in the NVP's that the OP seems to be interested in here.